# ObjectArrayArguments class

Tags: java, junit, java-stream, junit5

I try to write parametrized test in JUnit 5

```
@ParameterizedTest
@ArgumentsSource(TwoParameters.class)
public void test(int a, int b){
    //some assert
}

static class TwoParameters implements ArgumentsProvider {

    @Override
    public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        return Stream.of(
                ObjectArrayArguments.create(1, 2),
                ObjectArrayArguments.create(3, 4));

    }
}
```

As you can see, there is test function which takes 2 parameters.
I saw one method with `@CsvSource` and this
I Try to use method above, but I cant return stream contains 2 parameters for the test.

`ObjectArrayArguments` cannot be resolve.
How to import this class?
I tried `import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ObjectArrayArguments;` but it does not work (Intelij says 'Cannot resolve symbol ObjectArrayArguments')

Comment: Can you clarify how "it does not work"? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Mureinik I edit question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectArrayArguments` is not a member of JUnit.

You need to provide a stream of `Arguments`. You may use the factory method `Arguments.of(Object...)` to create such instances:

```
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of(1, 2),
        Arguments.of(3, 4)
    );
```

For further details read the user-guide at http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

Here is an excerpt using `MethodSource`:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("stringIntAndListProvider")
void testWithMultiArgMethodSource(String str, int num, List<String> list) {
    assertEquals(3, str.length());
    assertTrue(num >=1 && num <=2);
    assertEquals(2, list.size());
}

static Stream<Arguments> stringIntAndListProvider() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of("foo", 1, Arrays.asList("a", "b")),
        Arguments.of("bar", 2, Arrays.asList("x", "y"))
    );
}
```

Comment: What does it mean: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/ObjectArrayArguments.html

Comment: A glitch in the Matrix, erm JavaDoc. It is no longer part of the API: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/tree/master/junit-jupiter-params/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider

Comment: The JavaDoc package list also does not show it: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org/junit/jupiter/params/provider/package-summary.html

Comment: It's now removed from the Javadoc on the website. Thanks for noticing!